# How do I multi-thread a start-process in a for loop?

Tags: powershell

I have this little problem I am hoping you can help me with.
We rar a directory at night that has about 300 files, when raring it does it one at a time. I would like to do 5 or so with out doubling up on ones already processed.
here is my current script, how do I make it so it can do 5 at a time?

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem V:\SQL_Server_Backups

ForEach ($File in $Files) 
{ 
    $fullname = $File.fullname
    $rar = "m[f] -ep -m4 -mt8 -ri12 D:\RAR\$File.rar $Fullname"
    start-process -File "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" -ArgumentList $rar -Wait 
}
```

Now I have spent the last few hours trying to get my head around Runspace, Run-Jobs, installing different multi threaded scripts, but I am so lost its not funny.
I am really hoping there is a simple way to run this, without having to install additional modules or messing around with other stuff. As I want to be able to move this with out having to install additional stuff to get it to work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your attempts (using runspaces, run-jobs etc.), and explain how it fails, and we'll try to help you out

Comment: take a look at posh-rsjob. braindead runspaces

Comment: use `start-job`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke-Parallel script worked perfect for me

https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel

```
. "C:\_Batch_Jobs\Invoke-Parallel.ps1"
$Files = Get-ChildItem V:\SQL_Server_Backups

$Files | Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock {
    $fullname = $_.fullname
    $rar = "m[f] -ep -m4 -mt8 -ri12 D:\RAR\$_.rar $Fullname"
    start-process -File "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" -ArgumentList $rar -Wait
} -throttle 10
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried, but it says I need to wait 2 days. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this :

```
ForEach ($File in $Files) 
{ 
    $fullname = $File.fullname
    $rar = "m[f] -ep -m4 -mt8 -ri12 D:\RAR\$File.rar $Fullname"
    $scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create("start-process -File ""C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe $rar""")
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock 
}
```

Comment: Depending on the number of items in `$Files` this may result in many more concurrent jobs than "5 or so"

Comment: There is over 300 files, so thats going to spawn 300 of them anyway to specify 5 etc?