# Invoke-Parallel is waiting when using Start-Process

Tags: multithreading, powershell

Does anyone know why [Invoke-Parallel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) is not multithreading? When I run through this loop, it does not start the next scriptblock until the previous one finishes.

Note I tried this on [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) as well.

I am running a Java jar file for each file found. If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612556/how-do-i-multi-thread-a-start-process-in-a-for-loop) they are using the Start-Process command and wait for rar.exe.

```
 . .\Invoke-Parallel.ps1

 $ScriptBlock = {
        start-Process -file java -ArgumentList @('-jar',"a:\conversion.jar",$_.FullName,"$($_.FullName).tmp") -Wait
 }

 ForEach ($file in (GCI -Path b:\*)) {
   Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $file -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Throttle 5 
 }
```

*Note that this is just a simple example, my original script is more complex but I narrowed it down to this entry which is causing the multithreading to not multithread.

Answer (score 0):

These multithreading tools ([Invoke-Parallel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) & [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob)) require **pipelining**

I didn't pipeline my original code because I thought it was cleaner using a loop. But using a pipe does work.

```
. .\Invoke-Parallel.ps1

$ScriptBlock = {
  start-Process -file java -ArgumentList @('-jar',"a:\conversion.jar",$_.FullName,"$($_.FullName).tmp") -Wait
 }

(GCI -Path b:\*) | Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $_ -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Throttle 5
```